# Creating pyinstaller from my script, missing PySide2.QtXml in the result

Tags: python, qt, pyinstaller, pyside2

What I did was call

```
pyinstaller example.py
```

the pyinstaller gets all the important libraries for my script. I might be worth mentioning that I am working on a Windows machine. But when i run the result it tells me:

```
λ .\example.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "example.py", line 6, in <module>
  File "c:\applications\anaconda\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 714, in load_module

    module = loader.load_module(fullname)
ImportError: could not import module 'PySide2.QtXml'
[7684] Failed to execute script example
```

So there are two questions here:

1. I can not find a library called "PySide2.QtXml" in my python installation. So I assume the .dll has a different name? What would actually the real name of the .dll be? I found **Qt5Xml.dll** but I can't tell if this is the right library.
2. Once I have my library I'd like to add it to my example.spec file. Documentation says it has to look something like this:

   ```
   binaries=[ ( '/usr/lib/libiodbc.2.dylib', 'libiodbc.dylib' ) ],
   ```

   But I am not sure how to apply that to my currently missing library. I assume

   ```
   binaries=[ ( 'C:\somepath\Qt5Xml.dll', 'Qt5Xml.dll' ) ],
   ```

   would be the way to go?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: My solution for now is to just import something fomr QtXml so pyinstaller will know that this lib must be included as well. This is not a good solution though. If somebody know better please let me know! Example: "from PySide2.QtXml import QDomNode"

Answer (score 10):

I faced the same issue,
it looks like it is a hidden import, which you can add to your spec file or on the command line:

```
pyinstaller --hidden-import PySide2.QtXml example.py
```

or within your Spec file:

```
a = Analysis(['start.py'],
         pathex=['/some/path'],
         binaries=[],
         datas=[],
         hiddenimports=['PySide2.QtXml'],
         hookspath=[],
         runtime_hooks=[],
         excludes=[],
         win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
         win_private_assemblies=False,
         cipher=block_cipher,
         noarchive=False)
```

Comment: Thanks, I simply added this to my script `from PySide2 import QtXml` and it worked fine. No command line parameters needed.